# CMake and GTest linking tests

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I want build and test a small project of mine with cmake and gtest. In the project I have a function `readModel(...)` where the definition and implementation is separated. The project builds fine but I get the following linker error for the test of `readModel(...)`

```
cd /home/kain88/Desktop/example/build/test && /usr/bin/cmake -E  cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/example_test.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++   -Wall -std=c++14   CMakeFiles/example_test.dir/pdb_test.cpp.o  -o example_test -rdynamic ../ext/gtest-1.7.0/libgtest.a ../ext/gtest-1.7.0/libgtest_main.a ../ext/gtest-1.7.0/libgtest.a -lpthread 
CMakeFiles/example_test.dir/pdb_test.cpp.o: In function `PDB_TEST_readModel_Test::TestBody()':
pdb_test.cpp:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `readModel(std::string const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems that cmake is not including the `*.o` file generated in the `src` folder for the test. How can I tell cmake that it should include the `*.o` files from the `src` folder also for the test?

This is the CMakeLists.txt I use in the test folder.

```
# enable GTest
enable_testing()
include_directories(${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

# Unit Test
set(PROJECT_TEST_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME_STR}_test)
file(GLOB TEST_SOURCES "*.cpp")
add_executable(${PROJECT_TEST_NAME} ${TEST_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_TEST_NAME} gtest gtest_main)
add_test(test ${PROJECT_TEST_NAME})
```

A complete striped down example case can be [found here](https://github.com/kain88-de/example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may create an object library target that compiles the .o object files:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(${PROJECT_NAME}_objects OBJECT ${SRC_FILES} ${INCL_FILES})
```

Use the result of it on both your lib/exe and test:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(${PROJECT_NAME} $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${PROJECT_NAME}_objects>)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(${PROJECT_TEST_NAME} ${TEST_SOURCES} $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${PROJECT_NAME}_objects>)
```

PS: You can use the same trick to compile the objects shared by multiple targets only once, for example, a shared and a static library target.